# PHP OOP constructing class property form method in same class

Tags: php, class, methods, construct

For some reason I can't get this to work:

```
<?php 
class Number{
    public $number;
    public $number_added;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->number_added = $this->add_two();
    }

    public function add_two(){
        return $this->number + 2;
    }
}   
?>
```

`$this->number` is set from Database, `$this->number_two` should be DB value + 2. However, when I echo `$this->number_added`, it returns two. The `$number` value was initialized correctly. This is a simplified example of my problem just to see if what I am trying to do possible? PHP OOP beginner.

Comment: well your class methods are outside of your actual class, for one..

Comment: Sorry, typo, you responded while I was editing! :) Thanks!.

Comment: You told that you are getting the class from db.. means with PDO using fetchClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting the `$number` property anywhere prior to its use in `add_two()` (via the constructor), therefore PHP evaluates it as `0` during the addition.

You should pass in initial state during object construction, for example

```
public function __construct($number) {
    $this->number = $number;

    $this->number_added = $this->add_two();
}
```

### Update

Allow me to illustrate the problem. Here's your current code and how I imagine you're using it

```
$number = 2;

$obj = new Number();
// right here, $obj->number is null (0 in a numeric sense)
// as your constructor calls add_two(), $obj->number_added is 2 (0 + 2)

$obj->number = $number;
// now $obj->number is 2 whilst $obj->number_added remains 2
```

Using my updated constructor, here is what happens

```
$number = 2;

$obj = new Number($number);
// $obj->number is set to $number (2) and a call to add_two() is made
// therefore $obj->number_added is 4
```

Comment: he said $number is set from the database, probably somewhere we can't see since it is a public variable.

Comment: @DavidHarris He isn't setting it before the call to `add_two()` in the constructor though, therefore it is undefined.

Comment: oh, yeah -- I didn't really think about that lol.

Comment: I am initializing $number straight from the DB result. If I echo it there is a value associated with it.

Comment: @Jursels, what he is trying to say is that $number is still 0 until after `Number::add_two()` has finished.

Comment: @Jursels When are you setting it? If it's after object creation (via `new Number()`), then it's too late to be used in the constructor

Comment: Phill, I create the object, then make a MYSQL query and instantiate the object by looping through the result and then I add the instatiated object to an array holding the object.

Comment: @Jursels I've updated my answer with some explanations

Comment: I see what you mean Phill. __construct runs immediatly after the new Number(), so $number is empty.

Comment: @Jursels No, the constructor does **not** run after `new Number()`, it **is** `new Number()`. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: I see, so is there something else than constructor to use if I want to dynamically create a property from other properties in the same class?